# how do you make the textInput component multiline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, textinput

How do  you make the textInput component multiline.There is nothing in the properties or in the component inspector.is there a way to do it with AS3.I searched in many forums but i did not get any solution.Anyone knows help me.

Comment: There should be no answer to that question. In AS3 there are many TextInput component classes existing so since you never say what framework you are using no answer should be provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
var t:TextField=new TextField();
t.type =TextFieldType.INPUT;
t.multiline=true;
addChild(t);
```

Or, if you are adding it manually just change behavior in properties panel from single line to multiline.

Comment: am not asking about TextField..asking about TextInput component.@Antizam

Answer (score 0):

You can not make a [`TextInput`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextInput.html) component multiline because it's simply a single-line text component :

> The TextInput component is a single-line text component that contains a native ActionScript TextField object.

Instead, you can use a [`TextArea`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextArea.html) component which is a multiline text field :

> The TextArea component is a multiline text field with a border and optional scroll bars.

Hope that can help.

Comment: PO never says which framework this TextInput is from. How would you know which one he is talking about?

Comment: @BotMaster It's clear that OP used Flash CS6 (mentioned as tag) where we have only one TextInput component, so there is absolutely no difference if he is speaking about Flash or AIR, in addition, what I said is also true for the [TextInput for Flex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextInput.html). So I don't see why you have downvoted my answer ?

Comment: Yes,akmozo is right.I mentioned tag as flash cs6.Am using Flash.and the answer told by akmozo is correct.thank you akmozo.@BotMaster

Comment: Thank you for everybody who didn't like my answer to put a comment why he downvotes it.